# How to add a view programmatically to an xml layout in android?

Tags: android

Hiiii there, I have an xml layout and when a button is clicked I need to add a TableLayout view to that xml layout. I know how to do this with simple stuff like text views but tables would seem to be a lot harder to define programmatically, Im not quite sure what inflating is but is that what I should be using? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the layout in an xml file and then simply inflate that layout using the `LayoutInflater`. This will give you a `View` (in your case this will be a TableLayout), then add this view and you are done.

Reference: [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

Comment: so i would have my xml with all my other stuff in, then i could inflate that layout with my TableLayout xml layout?

Comment: Right, define another layout xml file with your TableLayout, then inflate that file and add the view programmatically.

Comment: any chance you could tell us what inflate exactly means LOL does it mean getting all the stuff from the xml so you can use it in the code?

Comment: Inflate means take the xml definition and create the objects for the views with their configuration. Think of it as when you call "setContentView" in your Activity. I've added a reference to the method you need to use.

Comment: kk thanks D: i think i get it nearly lol i just read the inflate arguments which i need and confused the shit outa myself

Comment: Notice that you can provide a parent view (so your inflated layout takes the layout params of the parent) and a boolean to specify wether you want to attach the inflated view to the provided parent view (in this case you don't have to manually add the view).

Comment: butt i thought the inflated layout is like the whole xml file so how does it even have parent layout params arrrr baffed lol

Comment: after ive infalted my tablelayout with         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
             (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      inflater.inflate(R.layout.table4, null); how do i add it to my other layout? cheers :p

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout, let's say you want to add the TableLayout inside a RelativeLayout with an id of relativeLayout1.

To add it, you would do the following code:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLAyout();

// Code to add rows and views to the table

R.findViewById("relativeLayout1").add(table);
```